# How to dynamically generate CSS class and/or set its property

Tags: css, angular

The title is not really a question it is more like an idea, I don't know what approach is best for my situation.

So, the problem. I have some 3rd party component that have some complex structure and styling. Some part of it has some predefined CSS class that I can override with CSS in my surrounding component. Something like this:

my component:

```
<div class="my-cmp-container">
    <some-3rd-party-cmp></some-3rd-party-cmp>
</div>
```

3rd party component:

```
<div class="3rd-party-css-class">
    ...
</div>
```

For example, `3rd-party-css-class` has style `background-color: #f00`, I can override it with `.my-cmp-container .3rd-party-css-class { background-color: #fff; }` etc. But. What if I need to set color dynamically, it's stored in a DB for example and I can't predefine each case in my class' CSS. I just have the color in hex.

In theory I can generate unique string to set as CSS class for every instance of `some-3rd-party-cmp` and somehow generate CSS in my component? I'm lost a little, what is the best approach for this?

**Edit:** Code sample to illustrate the situation https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxdatq

Comment: The 3rd party component doesn't make styling properties available for data binding?

Comment: Check [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [`[ngStyle]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Comment: @ConnorsFan of course not otherwise there would be no question. :)

Comment: I added code sample on stackblitz to illustrate the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is the subject of [this open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26800) about stylesheet binding in Angular. Until that feature is available, you can get what you want with a custom directive. Here is a directive that retrieves the checkbox element generated by `ng-zorro-antd` and applies two color attributes to it. The two colors are `@Input` properties and the directive implements `OnChanges` which allows to react to property binding changes.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[nz-checkbox][nz-chk-style]"
})
export class CheckBoxStyleDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input("nz-chk-bkgnd") chkBkgndColor: string;
  @Input("nz-chk-border") chkBorderColor: string;

  private checkbox: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkbox = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".ant-checkbox-inner");
    this.updateBackgroundColor();
    this.updateBorderColor();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.chkBkgndColor) {
      this.updateBackgroundColor();
    }
    if (changes.chkBorderColor) {
      this.updateBorderColor();
    }
  }

  updateBackgroundColor() {
    if (this.checkbox) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.checkbox, "background-color", this.chkBkgndColor);
    }
  }

  updateBorderColor() {
    if (this.checkbox) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.checkbox, "border-color", this.chkBorderColor);
    }
  }
}
```

Once the directive attribute selector `nz-chk-style` is applied to the 3rd party element, you can set the checkbox background and border colors with property binding as follows:

```
<span nz-checkbox nz-chk-style [nz-chk-bkgnd]="bkgndColor" [nz-chk-border]="borderColor" >
```

See [this interactive stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewv5m5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Not the same behavior as of original checkbox but I've got the idea. Thank you, this is much better then changing css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Angular but you tagged it, so I guess you are.

If you want to change only the color and nothing more, instead of having a .3rd-party-css-class class, you could just have your  with an ng-style like so:

```
<some-3rd-party-cmp ng-style="{ color: your_color_hex_variable }"></some-3rd-party-cmp>
```

You can also define a whole object if styles and pass it.

You can also use ng-class and pass one or an array of class names what you want to put additionally on your component:

```
<some-3rd-party-cmp ng-class="[cls1, cls2, cls3]"></some-3rd-party-cmp>

<some-3rd-party-cmp ng-class="[3rd-party-css-class, someCondition ? 'another-class-name' : '']"></some-3rd-party-cmp>
```

In the classes you can define the css rules you want to apply and thats it.

With this solutions you can avoid having extra wrapper elements for styling purposes which is a nice thing.